# How do I access properties of an object that's inside of an array that's inside of an array that's inside of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What I'm trying to do is access object information that's inside of nested arrays. Something like:

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var people=[[[]]];
var person = {
    firstName : "John",
    lastName  : "Doe",
    age       : 50,
    eyeColor  : "blue"
};
people[0][0][0].push(person);
document.getElementbyId("demo").innerHTML=people[0][0][0]person.lastName;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that to access element 0 of an array I'd use array[0]. I know that to access an attribute of an object I'd use object.attribute. But I can't seem to figure out how to access object attributes inside of an array. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: You have one `[0]` too many in that push operation.

Comment: And you access it like `people[0][0][0].lastName`

Answer (score 1):

Your one array short for your sample code. Your code results in

```
var people=[[[]]];
var person = {
    firstName : "John",
    lastName  : "Doe",
    age       : 50,
    eyeColor  : "blue"
};
people[0][0][0].push(person);
```

returns: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

you need to change

```
var people=[[[]]];
```

to

```
var people=[[[[]]]];
```

then you can just do

```
people[0][0][0][0].firstName
```

returns: "John"

Answer (score 0):

Correct code snippet below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
      var people=[[[]]];
      var person = {
            firstName : "John",
            lastName  : "Doe",
            age       : 50,
            eyeColor  : "blue"
      };

       people[0][0].push(person);   
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = people[0][0][0]["firstName"];
</script>
</body>
</html>
```